# How to avoid applying a regex search-and-replace more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this regular expression replace that transforms every YouTube URL into an Iframe:

```
str.replace(/((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)? (?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?)/gi, '<iframe src="https://youtube.com/embed/$2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>');
```

But this code will act even if it was already applied before to that Iframe.
So the code breaks up everytime I execute that function.

Is there a way to ignore the link if it already has `src=""` between it?

Comment: don't use regexs for parsing html.

Comment: because reg exp just look for the URL so guess what is in the iframe? The url.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex to change HTML

Note the code below will not run in the Stackexchange sandbox

```js
$("[href]").each(function() {
  if (this.href.indexOf("youtu")) {
    let url = new URL(this.href);
    const v = url.searchParams.get("v");
    $(this).replaceWith('<iframe src="https://youtube.com/embed/v='+v+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://youtu.be/-D5YGTkTBH4">Watch</a>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-D5YGTkTBH4" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```